# read_csv file importing error-Pandas Empty data error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Trying to import csv fiels and analyse for missing values, below is my code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  
import smtplib
import glob
import os
import sys

path = "/home/tmp"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path,"*.csv"))

for fname in all_files:
    print(fname)
    df_header = pd.read_csv(fname,header=None,skiprows=1,encoding='cp1252')
    print(df_header)

Error msg:
 df_header = pd.read_csv(fname,header=None,skiprows=1,encoding='cp1252')

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 542, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__

pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Please suggest solution for fixing this.

Sample Data

[image: Sample Data]

Output of head  -n5 path:

[image: Output of head -n5 path]

Comment: Could you show us the output of `head -n5 /home/tmp/*.csv`?

Comment: edited the post to include the output